# AG-Grid + Angular 6 = Compatible?

Tags: ag-grid, angular6

Just started with Angular, so obviously going with NG6

Trying to create a demo with AG-Grid to justify the cost of a paid version, but following the simple steps on their site to get started give me the error below.
Figured let me first make sure this component is compatible with Angular 6?

Cheers,
N

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'rowData' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'rowData' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("   style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
                class="ag-theme-balham" 
                [ERROR ->][rowData]="rowData" 
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
            </ag-grid-angular>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@11:16
Can't bind to 'columnDefs' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'columnDefs' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                class="ag-theme-balham" 
                [rowData]="rowData" 
                [ERROR ->][columnDefs]="columnDefs">
            </ag-grid-angular>

"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@12:16
'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        <div class="col-10">

            [ERROR ->]<ag-grid-angular 
                style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
                class="ag-t"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@8:12
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's compatible.

I've been a total idiot and added code in app-routing.module instead of app.module.  (n00b!!)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful while doing the ng build --prod. ag-grid 20.0.0 has issues with angular 6.0.0 prod build. It wont render the GRID. While doing the build set buildOptimization=false;